# Natural Earth doesn't render well in Robinson World projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, natural-earth

[image: Entire World Map]
QGIS Pisa 2.10.1 Mac Pro, Mac OS

I don't seem to be able to create a simple World Map using the Natural Earth Dataset and the Robinson World projection, unless I zoom in. What could be the problem?[image: Zoom]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a QGIS rendering issue.

Under `Settings -> Options, Rendering` tab, uncheck `Enable feature simplification by default for newly added layers`.

You have to remove and load again the Natural Earth dataset to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now the same happens with rasters and I don't have the same options. What to do?

Comment: It might help to reproject the raster first to the Robinson projection using `Raster -> Projections -> Warp`, and add the new file to the canvas. On-the-fly-reprojection has some issues on projections if points fall outside the valid range.