# Countries cutting off at the edges of Mollweide projection

Tags: qgis, proj

I have a custom CRS centering on the Pacific ocean with the Mollweide projection:

`+proj=moll +lon_0=-158 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +lon_wrap=-158`

My countries are split at the 22nd meridian, and look fine with a rectangular projection such as `+proj=cea`. Something about the curves at the edges is messing it up.

[image: countries cut off]

Also strange is the zooming behavior - as I zoom in on the edges, the curves of Africa & Antarctica at the edges are filled in. It only looks this way when I'm fully zoomed out to see the whole layer.

[image: mollweide zoom behavior]

Comment: It could be a problem with the rendering algorithm at the extreme, I have seen similar behavior in ArcGIS (~version 9.1), you could try simplifying the geometries for display or even rasterizing with scale dependent layers (raster/simple for zoomed out, original vector for zoomed in). If you know anyone with ArcGIS you could ask them nicely to run repair geometry over the data *as projected* just to be sure there's no bowtie/hourglass geometry errors causing mischief.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson aond the questions linked there.

Comment: which version of qgis are you using?

Comment: could be related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164364/natural-earth-doesnt-render-well-in-robinson-world-projection

Comment: @IanTurton tried the solution w both QGIS 2.18 and 3.0 and didn't work.. hmm.

Comment: @AndreJ Shouldn't be that - the shp was split at the correct meridian and then reprojected to Mollweide... Unless my +proj string is off somehow?

Comment: I guess your cutting line needs to be densified before reprojecting. It looks ok for me with Natural Earth world countries (which has more intersections with the cutline).

Comment: @AndreJ - I am procrastinating by going through some old questions of mine... you were right, the problem was I had not densified the line with enough points. If you "Answer" this question I can mark that as the correct answer, in case this helps any future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your cutting line needs to be densified before reprojecting. It looks ok for me with Natural Earth world countries (which has more intersections with the cutline).